# Bootstrap Datepicker not allowing dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

My Model

```
[UIHint("Date")]
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="", DataFormatString = " {0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; } // Date
```

Display Template Date

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new 
{

@class = "datepicker"

})
View

<div class="control-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "control-label" })
<div class="controls">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"

    });
```

Datepicker is still not allowing dd/mm/yyyy format date.
I have been figuring out the problem from days.

Comment: Changed dd/mm/yyyy into dd/mm/yy  in js and display template...
Now in edit view.. when i change date i shows like 20/12/13 But still the error follows The field Date must be a date.

Comment: Arno i think you are referring to jqueries docs..http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker check this link

Comment: Yeah it's true sorry my mistake

Comment: Do you know that the function ToShortDateString is culture sensitive did you check your culture settings to see in what form the date should be displayed ?

Comment: i have no culture attached to my app... this means my current systems culture should apply.. i have also changed current date format in dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Moreover Model.Value.ToShortDateString() it do not effect validation..

Comment: I know its old... but was a solution to this ever found?

Answer (score 0):

You should change from lowercase dd/mm/yyy to upper case like this:

```
$(function(){
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
     autoclose: true,
    viewMode: 'years',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
});
```